# Would a gelatinous mass be possible?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, creature-design

In the world I have been working on my planet has a gelatinous mass of cells coexisting but not a technical single creature. It bridges the gap between single celled and complex and it grows in size as it consumes organic matter (any organic matter). It divides in two like a bacteria when it reaches a large enough size. Is a creature like this possible and is there any known precedent?

Comment: Reality-check on the classic D&D gelatinous cube? Yes.

Comment: [Lekgolo](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Lekgolo) come to mind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are real world examples. You're looking for colony organisms or a collection of single-celled organisms living as one. The [siphonophorae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siphonophorae) is a colony organism. They're made up of individual animals though appear as a single animal.

[image]

The most familiar of these is the [Portuguese man o' war](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_man_o%27_war) (not pictured above).

Additionally there are the [slime molds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slime_mold). These things are [terrifying to watch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GY_uMH8Xpy0) in [time lapse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oAIDevwe1nI).

[image]

The most shocking thing about slime molds, which keep in mind are made up of single-celled organisms, ***they learn***. They can [remember, make decisions, and anticipate change](http://www.nature.com/news/how-brainless-slime-molds-redefine-intelligence-1.11811).

Comment: they also start to suffocate the inner cells if they get too big. This a major hurdle to overcome.

Comment: @John They could be as big as the story requires if they have active transport mechanisms like slime molds. You're probably thinking of the surface area to volume ratio limitation that applies single cells or mobility of large animals. It doesn't apply the same way here.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of [slime mold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slime_mold) is close.

Comment: What about Salps or other "superorganisms?" We like a bit longer and well-thought out answers. A little more information and this would be a good answer.